# PageLoad not working as expected in asp.Net Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, pageload

I have seen many posts on this but I still cannot find out why my code is still doing this.

I have 1 aspx page with 2 buttons on. In the pageload I check if it is the first time it loads using (!IsPostBack) and set a few variables I then go on to use in this page.

For some reason that I cannot explain this was working as expected and perfectly, but all of a sudden this section of the code is now being hit every time the page reloads after a button click. Meaning the variables are being newed up again and again and I lose the data every button click now, which is not what I want.

Here is the web form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%--  --%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="BrowserTalking.js"></script>
    <link href="LandingPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"/>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body onload="speaking();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="wholeScreenDiv">
        <div class="mainColumn">
            <asp:Label ID="questionLabel" runat="server" CssClass="questionText"></asp:Label>
            <div class="answerRow">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="myButton1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="myButton2" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="questionNumber" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SpeechSynthNeeded" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript Method called onload is just using a speech synthesis API and again this was the same before when it was working perfectly.

```
function speaking() {
    var questionNum = document.getElementById("questionNumber").value;
    var actualQuestion = "";
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utterance.rate = 0.7;

    if (document.getElementById("SpeechSynthNeeded").value == "1") {

        if (questionNum == 0) {
            actualQuestion = 'Can you read and understand this text clearly';
        } else if (questionNum == 1) {
            actualQuestion = 'Would you still like the information spoken to you?';
        } else if (questionNum == 2) {
            actualQuestion = "Do you suffer from Aphasia?";
        } else if (questionNum == 3) {
            actualQuestion = "Do you suffer from Hemianopia";
        } else if (questionNum == 4) {
            actualQuestion = "Would you like to setup an account?";
        }

        utterance.text = actualQuestion;
        speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
    }

}
```

and the code behind looks like this

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public ApplicationQuestion _Question;
    public ApplicationUser _User;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack) // Do all of this on the first time this page lods 
        {
            _User = new ApplicationUser();
            _Question = new ApplicationQuestion();

            questionLabel.Text = _Question.GenerateQuestion(0);

            Session["Question"] = _Question;
            Session["User"] = _User;

            questionNumber.Value = "0";
            SpeechSynthNeeded.Value = "1";
        }
        else // Do all within this else every time a question is answered
        {
            _Question = (ApplicationQuestion)Session["Question"];
            _User = (ApplicationUser)Session["User"];


            if (int.TryParse(questionNumber.Value, out int number))
            {
                number++;
                questionNumber.Value = number.ToString();
            }
        }

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(int.TryParse(questionNumber.Value, out int number))
        {
            //Generate Next Question
            questionLabel.Text = _Question.GenerateQuestion(number);
        }

        // Add 1 to the questions results list meaning the user answered Yes
        _User._QuestionResults.Add(1);

        if (int.TryParse(questionNumber.Value, out int number2))
        {
            // if it is on the first question and they answer yes then set SpeechSynthe Value to 0 so it isnt used in javascript for next question 
            if (number2 == 1)
            {
                SpeechSynthNeeded.Value = "0";
            }

            // if it is on the second question and they answer yes then set SpeechSynthe Value will be set back to 1 so its reactivated
            if (number2 == 2)
            {
                SpeechSynthNeeded.Value = "1";
            }

            // After Final question redirect to User login page
            if (number2 == 5)
            {
                Response.Redirect("UserLogin.aspx?synthNeeded=" + SpeechSynthNeeded.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

When debugging through the issue I get now is when I first click the button it goes into the pageLoad and goes into the Else (Which is what i want), but then the button click method is called and once this is finished it comes back into the page load and goes into the first part of the If/Else, and therefore sets up all the variables again and I lose the data I need.

I don't know if this is something tiny I have changed or I have just lost my mind from looking at it too long, but all Im trying to do is set up an object in the page load, then every button click I add a value to that object and then use that value later down the line. I am putting this object in the session to pull it back down when I need it.

Can anyone tell me why Im hitting the "First" page load again and again even with the use of (!IsPostBack) even after a button click?

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

One of the weirdest and most annoying things that has happened to me yet.

The removal of the line  from the aspx page stopped the double page loading and now it works as normal.

Thanks to https://forums.asp.net/t/1004939.aspx?Page_Load+called+twice+ I found someone else had solved the issue from playing around with src="" image tags.

I had added this for a speech recognition API and did not consider this to be making this happen and I still don't know why it does.